# Angular form button not enabling upon validated form

Tags: angular, validation

I'm following along with the fireship tutorial while making some changes but my submit button doesn't seem to switch from disabled to enable when my form validation should return true.

this is what i have so far for my sign-in in
html

```
<form [formGroup]="loginForm" novalidate>
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput type="text" placeholder="email" #email required >
  </mat-form-field>
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput type="password" placeholder="Password" #password required>
  </mat-form-field>
  <div class="d-flex flex-column align-items-center">
    <!-- Calling SignIn Api from AuthService -->
      <button mat-raised-button  class="button is-success w-100" type="submit" 
        (click)="checkSignIn(email.value, password.value)">
        Continue
      </button>
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="email.invalid || password.invalid" class="notification is-danger">
    Something isn't right with the Email or Password
  </div>
</form>
```

and in my ts

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.loginForm = this.fb.group({
      email: ['', [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.email
      ]],
      password: ['',
        Validators.required
      ],
    });
  }

  // Use getters for cleaner HTML code
  get email() {
    return this.loginForm.get('email')
  }

  get password() {
    return this.loginForm.get('password')
  }
  checkSignIn(email, password) {
    if (this.authService.SignIn(email, password))
    {

    this.authService.SignIn(email, password);
    console.log("email or password is wrong");
    }
  }
```

The console log is able to display "email or password is wrong" when i'm keying in a wrong user credentials if i remove `[disabled]="!loginForm.valid"` from the Continue button. I am also able to successfully get into the next page if user is logged in successfully.
However when I do disable if form is not valid, it doesn't seem to enable itself when I've keyed in an email and filled the password.
No error message as well.

What could I have missed that's preventing the login form validation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i see, you mixed Template-driven form and Model-driven(Reactive) form. I think, that's the main problem in your case. This code could be much simpler.

Your template should be:

```html
<form [formGroup]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="checkSignIn()">
  <mat-form-field>
    <input formControlName="email" name="email" matInput type="text" placeholder="email">
  </mat-form-field>
  <mat-form-field>
    <input formControlName="password" name="password" matInput type="password" placeholder="Password">
  </mat-form-field>
  <div class="d-flex flex-column align-items-center">
    <button mat-raised-button  class="button is-success w-100" type="submit" [disabled]="!loginForm.valid">
      Continue
    </button>
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="!loginForm.valid" class="notification is-danger">
    Something isn't right with the Email or Password
  </div>
</form>
```

Your component should be:

```ts
ngOnInit() {
  this.loginForm = this.fb.group({
    email: ['', [
      Validators.required,
      Validators.email
    ]],
    password: ['',
      Validators.required
    ],
  });
}

checkSignIn() {
  if (this.authService.SignIn(this.loginForm.value.email, this.loginForm.value.password))
  {
    this.authService.SignIn(this.loginForm.value.email, this.loginForm.value.password);
    console.log("email or password is wrong");
  }
}
```

As you can see, your code could be much more simple. Also it solves your problem.

More information about Reactive forms could be found here: https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

Answer (score 1):

in Angular 2 to all rest of versions you can use below code
In html file change and add [disabled]="loginForm.form.invalid" only.

```
<form #loginForm="ngForm"> 
  <button  [disabled]="loginForm.form.invalid" mat-raised-button  class="button is-success w-100" type="submit" 
    (click)="checkSignIn(email.value, password.value)">
    Continue
  </button>
</form>
```

In ts file add this:

```
loginForm : FormGroup;
```

Answer (score 0):

Want to add to the first answer, your form also needs

```
(ngSubmit)="loginUser()
```

something like this. And in Angular form Validation, you use something like this for error message for both email and password.

for Email:

```
<div class="alert alert-danger m-0 text-left animated shake fast"
    *ngIf="loginForm.get('email').hasError(validation.type) && (loginForm.get('email').dirty || loginForm.get('email').touched)">
```

and in your ts file, change

```
this.loginForm = this.formBuilder.group({
            email: new FormControl(
                '',
                Validators.compose([
                    Validators.required,
                    Validators.pattern('^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$')
                ])
            ),
            password: new FormControl(
                '',
                Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5)])
            )
        });
```

And lastly, nee to add  `formControlName="email"`